# how to build python datatable from git repo

Tags: linux, installation, py-datatable

I have cloned the git repo from https://github.com/h2oai/datatable on my linux machine. How do I build datatable from the cloned copy saved on my local machine? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to install it after going through the instructions in the following link https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Let us help the community as following way;

```
git clone https://github.com/your_user_name/datatable
cd datatable
# build a "production mode" datatable
make build
# build datatable in "debug" mode, without optimizations and with
# internal asserts enabled
make debug
```